# Disabling certain keys in Data Grid View

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to disable Character Input in a column of a Data Grid View in C# in other words I want to restrict Alphabertical input in a column of Data Grid View.

Can anyone tell me which event do I do this and how can id do this. If anyone can help me I will appreciate it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does it return `int` but not `bool`?

Comment: Because we are checking ASCII Code in this function and ASCII Code is an Integer.